# How to create dynamic socket.join(socket.room) using html buttons

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Consider we have 3 buttons in HTML but with same ID's

```
<button id="id1"> John </button>
<button id="id1"> Peter </button>
<button id="id1"> williams </button>
```

this is my socket.io script (client side)

```
 $(document).on("click", "id1", function() {
  var ButtonText = $(this).text();
  var logged_in_userName ="i am using this application";
  var currentRoom = logged_in_userName + "-" + ButtonText;
  var reverseRoom = ButtonText + "-" + logged_in_userName;

//event to set room and join.
  socket.emit('set-room', {
  name1: currentRoom,
  name2: reverseRoom
  });
  });
```

Server side script

```
socket.on('set-room', function (room) {
        //setting room and join.
        setRoom = function (roomId) {
            socket.room = roomId;
            socket.join(socket.room);
        };
    });
```

My scenario:

If i click on button 1 socket.join() need to happen for john and same as well for other buttons also with their respective names

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear exactly what you want the room name to be that you join, but you were doing a couple things wrong.  First, you were defining a function inside your event handler and then never calling that function.  Then, you were not accessing the data sent with the `set-room` message properly.

If the `reverseRoom` property is what you want the newly joined room to be, then change your server code to this:

```
socket.on('set-room', function (data) {
    // since socket.room only stores one room name, I assume you want to leave
    // any prior room before overwriting that property
    if (socket.room) {
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    }
    socket.join(data.reverseRoom);
    socket.room = data.reverseRoom;
});
```